# How to Fix "NEW or OLD references not allowed "?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to use new and old as referencing in my trigger but I don't know how to solve my problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifcomglob

AFTER UPDATE OF COMETAT on COMMANDE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW


DECLARE
  V_COMGLOB numeric;
  V_COMPROD P.PRODNUM%TYPE;
   CURSOR C_COMPROD IS
          SELECT P.PRODNUM
          FROM COMMANDE CM, COMMANDEGLOBALE CGN, PRODUIT P, CONCERNERGLOB CG, CONCERNER C
          WHERE CM.COMNUM = C.COMNUM
          AND C.PRODNUM = P.PRODNUM
          AND P.PRODNUM = CG.PRODNUM
          AND CG.COMGLOBNUM = CGN.COMGLOBNUM
          AND CGN.COMGLOBETAT = 'en constitution'
          AND CM.COMNUM=:new.COMNUM;

  CURSOR C_COMGLOB IS
          SELECT CGN.COMGLOBNUM
          FROM COMMANDE CM, COMMANDEGLOBALE CGN, PRODUIT P, CONCERNERGLOB CG, CONCERNER C
          WHERE CM.COMNUM = C.COMNUM
          AND C.PRODNUM = P.PRODNUM
          AND P.PRODNUM = CG.PRODNUM
          AND CG.COMGLOBNUM = CGN.COMGLOBNUM
          AND CGN.COMGLOBETAT = 'en constitution'
          AND P.PRODNUM=V_COMPROD
          AND CM.COMNUM=:new.COMNUM;

BEGIN
    OPEN C_COMPROD;
    LOOP
    FETCH C_COMPROD INTO V_COMPROD ;
        OPEN C_COMGLOB;
        LOOP
        FETCH C_COMGLOB INTO V_COMGLOB ;
        if(C_COMGLOB%ROWCOUNT) != 0   THEN
        UPDATE CONCERNERGLOB SET CONCERNERGLOB.qtecom = (CONCERNERGLOB.qtecom + (SELECT CONCERNER.QTECOM FROM CONCERNER, COMMANDE where COMNUM=:new.COMNUM AND PRODNUM=V_COMPROD)) WHERE CONCERNERGLOB.COMGLOBNUM=V_COMGLOB AND CONCERNERGLOB.PRODNUM=V_COMPROD;
        ELSE
        null;
        end if;
        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

CLOSE C_COMGLOB ;
END;
```

This is the Oracle error:

> 4082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
>         *Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.
>         *Action:   Remove any new or old references.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a statement level trigger which has no access to individual rows.

You apparently want a row level trigger, so you need to declare it as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verifcomglob
   AFTER UPDATE OF COMETAT on COMMANDE
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
   FOR EACH ROW --<< here
....
```

Comment: The cursors in the `declare` block reference  `COMMANDE`, which is the table that owns the trigger. So converting the trigger into FOR EACH ROW will lead to the mutating table problem.